# Find character frequency in a string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Im trying to find character frequency in a string,i wrote the following code,but it does'nt show any output.All im trying is to fill the character array with respective counts.

When i tried to debug,it some how gives output,but prints some garbage value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* Program for printing character frequency in string */
charcount(char *,int *);
int main()
{
    int n,i=0;
    printf("Enter n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char var[n];
    int count[100];                    // array for storing character frequency   
    printf("Enter string :");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",var);
    charcount(var,count);             // calling frequeny function
    for(i=0;i<strlen(count);i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n",count[i]);                         
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

 charcount(char *p,int *q)
 {
    for(;*p;p++)
    {
       q[*p]++;         
    }            
 }
```

Comment: I don't think `char var[n]` is allowed, you should define the size directly `char var[100]` or use `char * var = malloc(n * sizeof(char))` instead

Comment: @gpalex It's been allowed since C99

Comment: What do you expect from `strlen(count)`?

Comment: Initialize count to zero.

Comment: @Manoj Kumar You are doing strlen(count) where count is an integer. I dont think it will work as expected.

Comment: @krishnan .Thanks i got it,but how to iterate count array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have few problems in your code:

1. `count` array is not initialized.
2. You are applying strlen() on an integer array.
3. count array should be 256 (`count[256]`) to cover all possible ascii chars. For example, if your input is `abcd` you'll go out of bound of array as `d` is 100.
4. You are printing the wrong count:

   `printf("%d\n",count[i]);` should be        `printf("%d\n",count[var[i]]);`
5. Declare proper prototype for charcount().

After fixing these:

```
#include<stdio.h>
/* Program for printing character frequency in string */
void charcount(char *,int *);
int main()
{
    int n,i=0;
    printf("Enter n :");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char var[n];
    int count[256]={0};                    // array for storing character frequency   
    printf("Enter string :");
    scanf("%s",var);
    charcount(var,count);             // calling frequeny function
    for(i=0;i<strlen(var);i++)
    {
       printf("%d\n",count[var[i]]);                         
    }
    return 0;
}

void  charcount(char *p,int *q)
 {
    for(;*p;p++)
    {
       q[*p]++;         
    }            
 }
```

Make sure to compile  in C99 or C11 (e.g. `gcc -std=c99 file.c`) mode as VLAs are not supported in earlier standards of C.

Comment: why `strlen(var)` , we have to iterate using count array,because it contains the frequency of characters.

Comment: Yes, you want to iterate the count array. But you need to iterate the `strlen(var)` times using the elements of `var` array as indexes. For example, if your input is `abcd` then you only want to iterate 4 times, not 256 times. You may even put the strlen(var) outside the loop as size_t len = strlen(var) *may* be called in each iteration in case compiler fails to optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize your `count` array. Otherwise it will have garbage values in it by default. You can initialize the whole array to `0` like so:

```
int count[100] = {0};
```

Comment: Keep in mind the compiler may not produce optimal code here. I once had code that went through int by int writing 0 instead of just using memset with a length of 400.

Comment: You also fail to mention that most lowercase characters are out of bounds. A lowercase Z is 122.

Answer (score 1):

`int count` is nothing but a hashmap

Your code will not work for this string "abcd"

```
count['a'] = val // Works fine ASCII value of a is 97
count['b'] = val // Works fine ASCII value of a is 98
count['c'] = val // Works fine ASCII value of a is 99
count['d'] = val ; // Undefined Behaviour ASCII value of d is 100
```

The size should be equal to ASCII set length

```
int count[128] = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `count` array may not be large enough to hold all printable values (even assuming ASCII), and it should be 0 initialized. Your `for` loop should be checking against the length of `var`, not `count`, since you cannot sensibly treat the count integer array as a string.

```
int count[1<<CHAR_BIT] = {};
/*...*/
for(i=0;i<strlen(var);i++)
{
   printf("%d\n",count[var[i]]);                         
}
```

Well, it really depends on what you want to output. If you intend to output all of `count`, then:

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(count)/sizeof(count[0]);i++)
{
   printf("%d\n",count[i]);                         
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It supports non standard `char` sizes.

Answer (score 0):

> JAVA program to print "*" as much times as the occurrence of a character in String.
>   Or char_in_String : frequency of char_in_String
>   Instead of * you can print frequency count

```
public class CharFreq
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                String s = "be yourself ";                                                                                System.out.println(s);
                int r=0;
                char[] str = s.toCharArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
                {
                        int cnt = 0;
                        if (str[i] != ' ')
                        {
                                for (int j = 0; j < str.length; j++)
                                {
                                        if (str[i] == str[j])
                                        {
                                                cnt++;                                                                                                    r=j;
                                        }
                                }

                                if(i==r)
                                {
                                        System.out.print(str[i] + ":");
                                        for (int k = 1; k <=cnt; k++)
                                                System.out.print("*");
                                        System.out.println();
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

> Output:
>   be yourself 
>   b:*
>   y:*
>   o:*
>   u:*
>   r:*
>   s:*
>   e:**
>   l:*
>   f:*

Answer (score -1):

Your `count[100]` is not large enough. Assume you only enter "A - Z" or "a - z" it's still not large enough because 'z' is 122, then your charcount will increase count[122].

You should consider change `int count[100]` to `int count[128] = { 0 }`